# Generate 3D Mesh from extruded Polygon

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How to generate a 3D Mesh from a "2.5D" polygon with an additionally given extrusion? Preferably using a mature and well tested library in C++.

Background: I'm given a Geojson file which contains a simple type polygon geometry, including x,y,z data. I'm also given an "extrusion" parameter as part of the Feature Properties.

I was looking at CGAL, seems a good fit for the mesh generation. But I'm not sure about how to generate a geometry from the extruded 2.5D data, and I'm not sure what intermediate geometry type to use.

Edit:

Example data is a polygon with a hole (first ring / array of the data is the outer shell, second array (and all subsequent array by definition) is the hole. You can copy-paste this example to geojson.io (though it will show it in 2D only).

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [[35, 10, 1], [45, 45, 2], [15, 40, 2], [10, 20, 2], [35, 10, 1]],
        [[20, 30, 2], [35, 35, 2], [30, 20, 2], [20, 30, 2]]
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "extrusion": 10.5
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a (short) sample of your input dataset? Is this a point cloud?

Comment: @3Dave I updated the question. No this isn't a point cloud. The input is kind of geo data, where the geometry is an OGC Simple Type Polygon.